# How to exclude child elements when looping through categories?

Tags: assets, categories, relations, relatedto

I've got a few categories set up with a few child categories for each. Each one has assets (PDFs) assigned to them, by going into the assets, double clicking, and setting the category field there. So for example:

```
Category 1
-- asset 1
- Sub Category 1
-- asset 2
-- asset 3

Category 2
-- asset 4
- Sub Category 1
-- asset 5
-- asset 6
```

But when I'm looping through the related assets, using:

```
 {% for category in craft.categories.group('categoryGroup').level(1) %}
    {% set resources = craft.assets.relatedTo(category).find() %}
      {% for resource in resources %}
        {{ resources.title }}
      {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %
```

I get:

```
Category 1
- asset 1
- asset 2
- asset 3
- Sub Category 1
-- asset 1
-- asset 2
-- asset 3

Category 2
- asset 4
- asset 5
- asset 6
- Sub Category 1
-- asset 4
-- asset 5
-- asset 6
```

Which logically makes sense, that it's returning all assets related to the children categories, since those are also related to the parent. But how can I exclude them from the loop, so I only get back the assets that are directly related?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than preparing multiple queries - you can execute the `Query` in your field value

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('categoryGroup').level(1).find() %}
    {% for resource in category.fieldHandle.find() %}
        {{ resources.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %
```

Comment: not following. i get that it cuts down on queries but it doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: It should since you'll only fetch the related assets and not all of the hierarchy

Comment: hm, okay. the categories only have title fields, and it's throwing an error about invoking "find" on a string

Comment: Okay, then your initial code wasn't really good since you want to avoid the syntax you used in that case. However, categories don't work that way. You either need to create a custom field or use entries for that purpose since categories will relate all the way up to all hierarchy levels. When you relate a child, the parent will be related as well